# Why does a grouped data frame give key and data in a for-loop but does not work using map()?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the use case below, when I use a for-loop I can access both the key and grouped data but when trying to abstract the for-loop into using map() I get the following error:

```py
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'], 
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
df_grouped = df.groupby('last_name')

for key, group in df_grouped:
  print(key, group)

map(lambda x,y: sys.stdout.write(x, y), df_grouped)

>>> TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Here is my real-world example. I don't have a reproducible dataset I can post but I'm trying to create a line plot and seeing if map would clean up my code a bit.

```py
grouped_sim = raw_exprmt_dat.query('n > 1').groupby('model_id')
grouped_exp = raw_exprmt_dat.query('n == 1').groupby('model_id')

for key, group in grouped_sim:
  plt.plot(group['X'], group['Y'], label=key, color=color_map[key])
  if key == '365FGR':
    for key, group in grouped_exp:
      plt.plot(group['X'], group['Y'], 's', label=key, color=color_map[key], markersize=12)
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do with the last line?

Comment: @Efran Produce the same effect as the for-loop. `print()` does not work in lambda functions **For Python 2.7**.

Comment: Your goal is to only print? Or are you trying to aggregate the dataframe in some way?

Comment: I'm actually trying to create a line plot with several groups in my real-world case. I'm coming from R and really used to using map in my programming. I'm just trying to see if some of that same behavior can be mimicked in python.

Comment: Please don't. It's unclear what you're trying to do here and I think the paradigms of R are not helpful; it's really unclear to me how this should behave and the Python community would never write that

Comment: @roganjosh I can't really imagine how it could be unclear. Map is just an abstracted for-loop. All the OOP bros get all defensive when you question their methodology. Is there an answer to my question or not? Why does the for-loop get both variables but the map does not? I tried to make it as clear and simple as possible.

Comment: Is the father of the [the language](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) a "bro"?

Comment: `map(lambda x,y: sys.stdout.write(x, y), df_grouped)` is really unclear to me, and your edit for the real-world example has absolutely nothing to do with that code anyway. In any case, the result of the `map()` here is inconsequential because you just throw the result away

Comment: @roganjosh yes we all know it's a cardinal sin to try and implement FP practices using python. I wouldn't want to upset Guido! :( . Re: my map statement, obvi something is wrong w/ it hence the question. In the way way df_grouped gave key & group in the for-loop, I was expecting the same behavior using map but it didn't work. How do I get df_grouped to fess up the key and group vars in my map?

Comment: `map` is invisible. To my knowledge, you can't get interim values because it now creates an iterator. It either works or it doesn't.

Comment: Okay, that would make sense but I'll have to think about it. Seems like it should be fairly straight forward to convert a for-loop to a map(). BTW, if I can get the printing functionality to work in my map example then the plotting aspect would be trivial.

Comment: Well you shouldn't be using a `for` loop on the DataFrame anyway. I fear I've either missed the gist of your comments or you're sending yourself off-course because I'm barely following. I find R alien in many ways, and it's probably prudent to assume the reverse is true; most people than use Python don;t know pandas and the syntax is alien to them so you've managed to pile a lot of ambiguity into this question :)